# Color combination for my Button(Android)

Tags: android, colors, android-drawable

My LinearLayout has this image for background:
[Background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9px7.png)

I have this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="14dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:centerColor="COLOR1"
        android:startColor="COLOR2"
        android:endColor="COLOR3"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="270dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#878787"
        />
</shape>
```

Instead of COLOR1, COLOR2, color3 what colors I could use to the best possible contrast with the colors of the background.

Comment: Use your personal taste and your sense of beauty and color-harmony.

Comment: http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help: [Link](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/439945457319601854/)

For Instance: 
Color 1: #ED5565, Color 2: #DA4453